# Can I write a program to gather parameters in order to generate script to guide a binary file installation

Tags: perl, unattended-processing

OK, just as concept:

The base platform is Suse Enterprise server 11.1

I have a binary file to install; to install it, I need input some value such as ip address, cert location and so on.

Now what I want to do is to write a perl program to gather all input information first and then generate a script to guide the binary file install unattended.

Can it be done? I'm a fresh Perl learner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get paramters via Console, is to use the `Getopt` Module.
You can find further informations about that here:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

For example:

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $data = "bin_file";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose;
GetOptions ("length=i" => \$length, # numeric
"file=s" => \$data, # string
"verbose" => \$verbose
) # flag
or die("Error in command line arguments\n");
```

Then you can call your script (inside your shell) with:

```
$ perl script.pl --length 14 --file test.dat --verbose
```

`Getopt` parses the command line from `@ARGV` , recognizing and removing specified options and their possible values.